# Xcode label/uiimageview positioning issue?

Tags: xcode, position, label, uilabel

For some reason when I place a Label onto a view controller (at the top of the controller), that same Label appears at the bottom of the view controller when I run it in the simulator (even though I've clearly placed it at the top of the view controller).

Every time I drag something into position on my storyboard, it shows up 50 or 60 pixels to the left/right of where I placed it when I run it in the simulator.

Is this some kind of error? It's driving me nuts.

HELP!

Comment: How is Xcode responsible for this? Will you blame the paper sheet if you can't write proper english?

Comment: This only started happening to me recently (e.g. placing something in the center of a view controller, and having it shift up or down for no apparent reason when I run the app in the simulator).

Comment: Once verify disabling Auto Layout property in xib file.